# Best way to define tokens

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, compiler-optimization, lexer, javacc

I'm trying to optimize my javacc parser and I have a question about defining tokens in the grammar definition.

Is it good or bad practice? Does it affect much the performance of the parser.

example:

```
void name() :
{
  Token name;
}
{
  name = < NAME : ( < LETTER > | < DIGIT > ){2, 7}>
  {
    System.out.println(name.image);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't affect performance, but it will affect readability and maintainability. Keep in mind that the order of token definitions can make a difference to the meaning.  I suggest putting all token definitions up front.